# I want to compare 2000 data cells with 3000 other data cells in excel, but this takes very long

Tags: c#, excel

I've got two rows with data which I want to compare with each other to find duplicates. When I run my program it will take hours to complete this task, while it will take Excel a few seconds. But I don't want to do it in Excel because I wanna do it automatically. Row A = 2000 long and Row B = 3000 data long.

Here is what I did:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
   excel_init("C:\\blablatest");
            for (int j = 1; j < 2000; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 1; k < 2000; k++)
                {
                    if (excel_getValue("A"+j) == excel_getValue("B"+k))
                    {
                        excel_setValue("D"+j,"1");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(j);
                  //**STILL LOOP TAKES HOURS**
                }
            }
            excel_close();
            Console.ReadKey();

     }
        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass appExcel;
        private static Workbook newWorkbook = null;
        private static _Worksheet objsheet = null;

    //Method to initialize opening Excel
    static void excel_init(String path)
    {
        appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            // then go and load this into excel
            newWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, true, true);
            objsheet = (_Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to open file!");
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
            appExcel = null;
        }

    }
    static void excel_setValue(string cellname, string value)
    {
            objsheet.get_Range(cellname).set_Value(Type.Missing, value);
    }

    //Method to get value; cellname is A1,A2, or B1,B2 etc...in excel.
    static string excel_getValue(string cellname)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            value = objsheet.get_Range(cellname).get_Value().ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            value = "";
        }

        return value;
    }

    //Method to close excel connection
    static void excel_close()
    {
        if (appExcel != null)
        {
            try
            {
                newWorkbook.Close();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
                appExcel = null;
                objsheet = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                appExcel = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(How) can I make this faster???

Comment: perhaps you can load the 2 into separate DataTables and do the comparison that way.. meaning convert the data into datatable and or load the data if it's from a .csv into a datatable..

Comment: I don't know anything about c# but I know in VBA there's a huge overhead for looking at the table regardless of how many cells you're looking at at a time.  Is there a way to pull the entire sheet into a c# array instead of calling `excel_getvalue` 4,000,000 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are paying a huge overhead by doing the comparison inside `Excel`. What you should do is extract the data and compare it directly in your application.

The easiest way to do this is to convert `Excel` ranges to arrays:

```
var rowAArray = objsheet.Range["A1","A2000"].Value; //object[,] typed array
var rowBArray = objsheet.Range["B1", "B2000"].Value; //object[,] typed array
```

And now you just have to compare both arrays:

```
 for (int j = 1; j < 2000; j++)
 {
      for (int k = 1; k < 2000; k++)
      {
           if (rowBArray[k, 1] == rowAArray[j, 1])
               objsheet.Cells[j, 4].Value = 1; //Set value in cell "D*"
      }
  }
```

You will have to live with the boxing / unboxing penalty if you are handling numerical values but it will still be much faster than using `Excel` to perform the comparison.

Haven't tested the code but it should work.

Comment: @wouter Make sure you add `using Microsoft.Interop.Office.Excel` to your using directives.

Comment: I put the rows in the list, and it works now :) only problem I have: now I got: (int j = 1;j <2000;j++), but I want : (int j=1;j<row.length;j++). No idea how I do this

Answer (score 1):

Although your problem is well answered by InBetween and is going to be faster with removing that huge overhead, I must add that you don't need to compare all 2000 * 3000 entries for finding duplicated values, given that you have two sorted lists. Similar work can found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78397/finding-duplicates-in-two-sorted-arrays).

Let's sort your two lists, namely A and B(column number), to E and G. What about F? Store original row number of A, as E. For example, if a string "aabbb" was in A384 and now is in E1, store 384 in F1. Then compare two lists as link above, and for example, if you have a duplicate at E644, mark the cell "D"+(value of F644) with 1.

Originally you had O(AB) comparisons, by doing this you have O(AlogA + BlogB) for sorting. (Comparisons will only take O(max(A, B)).)

Note: In my opinion, implementing this is not going to be that easy and bug-free. I recommend first try InBetween's answer. Think about applying my suggestion only if it's still slow.